# Any and All with comparing a 2d list of keywords with a string

Tags: python

I have gotten this so far, but my goal is to check if the string has ANY nested ALL list of keywords in the string.

Currently I am receiving if ANY nested list with ANY element within the nested list that matches the keywords.

How would it be modified to output a boolean or which it shows any nest list but all elements of the nested list to match the string.

```
keyword_list = [
    [
        'purple',
        'sp',
        'blue'
    ],
    [
        'splash',
        'rocky'
    ],
    [
        'nike',
        'sacai'
    ]
]

product = "sport apples drinks water banana"


if any([keyword for keyword in keywords if (keyword in str(product).lower())] for keywords in keyword_list) == True:
    print(list([keyword for keyword in keywords if (keyword in str(product).lower())] for keywords in keyword_list))
```

Here is the simplified version which although works, I just wanted to know of any faster methods.

```
keyword_list = [
    [
        'purple',
        'sp',
        'blue'
    ],
    [
        'splash',
        'rocky'
    ],
    [
        'nike',
        'dr'
    ]
]

product = str("sport apples drinks water banana").lower()

def match(product):
    for keywords in keyword_list:
        keyword_match = 0
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword in product:
                keyword_match += 1
                if keyword_match == len(keywords):
                    return True

if match(product) == True:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example input and output. Also this is very ugly programming. Sometimes breaking up oneliners into multiple lines with straightforward logic makes it easier to understand on your own.

Comment: FYI: You don't need `== True`.

Comment: Use `re` instead of looping through each sub list.

Comment: The first code looks like a nightmare to read :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `any()` as the main loop, and `all()` as the inner loop.

```
def match(product):
    return any(all(keyword in product for keyword in keywords) for keywords in keyword_list)

match('sport apples drinks water banana') // False
match('blues purple sport rocky') // True
```